# UK 2017 Ford Fiesta Bluetooth issues

Tags: ford, fiesta, bluetooth, infotainment, sync

I am having issues with playing media trough Bluetooth on ford sync. Spotify on my phone seems to think the media is playing on the infotainment system but the infotainment system does not seem to have any awareness of the Bluetooth media playing.
This only worked the 1st date I had the can and has not worked since. Strange thing is hands free calls fork fine over Bluetooth. There is also an issue with intermittently working buttons on the steering wheel. Not sure if the issues are related (found a thread somewhere that suggested they might be but can't find the link now)
I've tried

- deleting the paired devices on both phone and sync interface.
- resetting sync on in the car
- pulling the sync fuse (which also seemed to reset sync)
- toggling the media option for the connected device in my phone settings
- took it to my local ford dealership but they outsource this type of work and advise I contact them directly and they are over an hour away from me.

The car was bought 2nd hand in the UK but I currently reside in Ireland.

Anyone here have any similar experience or might be able to provide some insight.

The Bluetooth media is the more important for me but if the buttons on the stearing wheel could be fixed too that would be a bonus.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

I never touch any Ford Fiesta before and only had a few cars in my life. But have a similar problem when switching to my current car, which uses an aftermarket android stereo.

If I get your question correctly, you want to stream your music/media through Bluetooth to be played on your stereo. Then it plays on your device (mobile phone?) speaker instead. While the phone call is already working properly to the car stereo.

In general, **your car stereo has different modes in it such as Radio, USB, Aux, Bluetooth, etc. The Bluetooth could be not automatically set as the default player. So you need to switch the stereo mode to Bluetooth**, in my case it is called A2DP. Can be a different term for different brands.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I can't see any option on the infotainment system to switch to bt media. If I play from Spotify on my phone it shows as playing on sync (fords infotainment system). It was working the 1st day I got the car but not since. Gone through all the menus and settings on the system and can't seem to find anything that makes a difference